# python if + else if statement

Tags: python, if-statement, command

I'm new to python so please kindly help, I don't know much.

I'm working on a project which asks for a command, if the command is = to "help" then it will say how to use the program. I can't seem to do this, every time I try to use the if statement, it still prints the help section wether the command exists or not.

**example: someone enters a command that doesn't exist on the script, it still prints the help section.**

```
print("welcome, to use this, please input the options below")
print ("help  |  exit")


option = input("what option would you like to use? ")

if help:
    print("this is a test, there will be an actual help section soon.")
else:
    print("no such command")
```

Comment: You can use if and elif https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/if-elif-else

Comment: Try ` if option == 'help': print('help')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check using `==` equality operator

```
print("welcome, to use this, please input the options below")
print("help  |  exit")


option = input("what option would you like to use? ")

if option == "help":
    print("this is a test, there will be an actual help section soon.")
else:
    print("no such command")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference your variable `option` in the `if` statement for it to work.

```
print("welcome, to use this, please input the options below")
print ("help  |  exit")


option = input("what option would you like to use? ")

if option == "help":
    print("this is a test, there will be an actual help section soon.")
else:
    print("no such command")
```

I'm also just starting with Python and I hope we both can learn a lot from here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 `print("welcome, to use this, please input the options below")
print ("help  |  exit")


option = input("what option would you like to use? ")

if option == "help":
    print("this is a test, there will be an actual help section soon.")
else:
    print("no such command")`
```